# is it possible to force crypt return NULL in this situation?

Tags: c, linux

is there any way to force `crypt` return `NULL`?
PASSWORD is constant, I cannot change it. I can set the environment variable to change the `auth`, but it cannot be `NULL`.
Any idea?

```
define PASSWORD="XXXXXXX"
char *auth;

if ((auth = getenv("ENV_AUTH")) == NULL || strcmp(crypt(auth, PASSWORD), PASSWORD) != 0)
```

Comment: Why? ..........

Comment: It's a wargame, I try to bypass the clause. I guess the way to do that is to produce a NULL because NULL == 0

Comment: But it's `strcmp(crypt(...), PASSWORD) != 0` and passing  NULL or 0 to strcmp is undefined behavior and most probably will never be equal to 0. The source code is available [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/crypt/crypt-entry.c#L79) I think you could fool it, just create `/proc/sys/crypto/fips` with a single integer using some kernel module, and it looks like it will return NULL.

Comment: by my test, it can NULL can pass the claus,root@linux1:/home/test# gcc test.c -o test
root@linux1:/home/test# ./test
aaa
root@linux1:/home/test# more test.c
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crypt.h>

int main(void)
{
        if(NULL == 0) {
                printf("aaa\n");
        }
        return 0;
}

Comment: I cannot create /proc/sys/crypto/flips file, /proc/sys is a root dir, I dont have permission to write.

Comment: @KamilCuk isn't that exactly the point of the exercise? Leverage the user controlled `auth` in order to make the buggy code crash? Also, would you please elaborate how turning that fips sysctl on will make crypt(3) return NULL?

Comment: In this practice, I have limited permission on this Linux system. I cannot use root to install any package or change any system setting in /etc. The only direction can be used is /tmp. Besides, do you think the environment variable is the key to this puzzle? Is it possible to using interger overflow to make crypto return NULL? It's just gussing.

Comment: I found buffer overflow for crypt is impossible, it only uses the first 8 characters in crypt.